# Passar parâmetro Javascript para PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

**Quero passar 2 (dois) parâmetros da minha pagina javascript para uma pagina PHP.**
Ja pesquisei na net, e só encontro essa lógica quando o PHP esta na mesma pagina do javascript.

Alguém sabe se isso é possível? e como fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Não é possível**, à menos que esteja tentando efetuar requisição `HTTP` (ajax, formulários, etc).

Isto por que JavaScript roda `client side` (navegador) enquanto o PHP roda `server side` (servidor) e o único caminho do `JavaScript` (client) até o `PHP` (server) é por meio de requisição `HTTP`.

**Exemplo - Ajax:**

**`ajax.html`**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "algum.php",
  data: { meuParametro1: "valor 1", meuParametro2: "valor 2"},
  complete: function(data){
            // (...)
        }
});
```

**Exemplo - Formulário:**

**`formulario.html`**

```
<form action="algum.php" method="post">
    <<input type="text" name="meuParametro1" value="valor 1">
    <<input type="text" name="meuParametro2" value="valor 2">

    <<input type="button" name="btEnviar" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

**`algum.php`**

```
$parametro1 = $_POST['meuParametro1'];
$parametro2 = $_POST['meuParametro2'];
```

Comment: Mas do jeito que que fez seria com apenas 1 variável.
Como seria com 2 variáveis.

E como eu pegaria este valor no meu arquivo PHP

Comment: @EduardoF.Santos, atualizei minha resposta com dois exemplos!

Comment: @EduardoF.Santos, basta utilizar virgula para mais de um parâmetro. É um objeto, então possui chave (`meuParametro1`, sem aspas) e valor ("`valor 1`", com aspas).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar quantas variáveis quiser. Exp:

```
data: { parametro: "valor", prametro2: "valor", parametro3: "valor"}
```

Ou passar do PHP assim:

```
var valor1= '<?php echo "valor"; ?>'
var valor2 = '<?php echo "valor"; ?>'

data: { parametro: valor1, parametro2: valor2}
```

Comment: E como eu pegaria essa variável no PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {variavel: 'valor'} ,
      url: "arquivo.php",
      success: function(resposta){
          alert(resposta);
      }  
    });
```

Dessa forma vc dá um POST do Javascript pro PHP.

Comment: No caso tenho dois valores a serem passados, então seria assim 

`$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {variavel: 'valor'} ,
      data1: {variavel1: 'valor1'} ,
      url: "arquivo.php",
      success: function(resposta){
          alert(resposta);
      }  
    }); `