# Como passar valor do javascript para AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Tenho uma função javascript que possui um código AJAX dentro dele.
Queri passar os valores do javascript para o AJAX, segue o código:

```
    function validarCamposComprar() {

    var campoNomeEmpresa = document.getElementById('fTxtCadastroNomeEmpresa');
    var campoNomeAdmin = document.getElementById('fTxtCadastroNomeAdmin');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "email.php",
        data: { meuParametro1: campoNomeEmpresa, meuParametro2: campoNomeAdmin },
        complete: function (data) {
            // (...)
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

É possível fazer isto, o que estou errando?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema é que com

```
var campoNomeEmpresa = document.getElementById('fTxtCadastroNomeEmpresa');
```

você obtém um elemento do DOM. Acredito que você queira enviar o valor ou o texto, se for esse o caso, faça

```
var nomeEmpresa = document.getElementById('fTxtCadastroNomeEmpresa').value;
var nomeAdmin = document.getElementById('fTxtCadastroNomeAdmin').value;
```

que retornam string

Comment: Isso ai @paulojean, arrumei na minha resposta, não tinha reparado nisso.

Answer (score 4):

É possível e deve ser feito.

Utilizando o elemento data do AJAX ou passando diretamente na URL.

Costumo fazer desta maneira:

```
var campoNomeEmpresa = $('campo1').value;
var campoNomeAdmin= $('campo2').value;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "email.php?meuParametro1=" + campoNomeEmpresa + "&meuParametro2=" + campoNomeAdmin,
    complete: function (data) {
        // (...)
    }
});
```

Comment: Como consigo pegar esses valores passados, no meu arquivo PHP?

Comment: Sim, arrumei o exemplo conforme a resposta abaixo.

Comment: @EduardoF.Santos na [tua outra pergunta o Felipe Douradinho já respondeu a isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/72501/129), usando o `$_POST`. Vê no fim da resposta.