# Como passar o valor de uma variável js para uma variável php

Tags: php, javascript

Eu tenho um arquivo js que manipula as variáveis, mas preciso passar essas variáveis para php para inseri-las no banco de dados.

Comment: Faça o [tour] para aprender a utilizar o site. Verás que ali do lado direito da página há uma lista de perguntas relacionadas com exatamente 10 perguntas que respondem a sua dúvida. Leia-as e se ainda restar alguma dúvida, pode voltar aqui, [edit] a pergunta e descrever em detalhes qual é o problema.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Passar parâmetro Javascript para PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72498/passar-par%c3%a2metro-javascript-para-php)